# Data Cleaning Bloomberg to R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, bloomberg

I have a project at my work where I need to Import historical prices from Bloomberg, and store it into an excel file. I wrote a code but the problem is that it always add a column "date" before every stock price. I would like to have only the first column that display the date and the other columns would only be the historical prices.
Here's my code :

````
install.packages("Rblpapi")

# Load package

library(Rblpapi)

# Connect to Bloomberg
blpConnect()

# Assign tickers and fields
tickers <- c("SPX INDEX","BXIIE3MC Index")
myField <- "PX_LAST"

# Pull Bloomberg data and create data frame

Benchmark <- as.data.frame(
  bdh(tickers,
      myField,
      start.date = as.Date("2019-12-31"),
      include.non.trading.days = TRUE)
)```
````

Comment: Why don't you use the Excel addin directly? In that case you can use the "dates" parameter with S (for show) for the first series and H (for hide) for the other series.

Comment: The issue is that the underlying Bloomberg API returns the data security by security, and does not aggregate the data. All the aggregation is done by the wrapper around this API on the client side. One solution is to do separate calls for each of the securities, and then combine the dataframes using Date as the index (this has the additional benefit that the securities come back in the order you asked for them, which is not always guaranteed). In Excel you can use BQL() to construct a direct database query as an alternative to multiple BDH calls.